How do I install something on an container-registry.oracle.com/graalvm image?
Following Dockerfile:
FROM --platform=linux/aarch64 container-registry.oracle.com/graalvm/native-image:21

RUN echo " --- Java version:"; java --version; echo "$JAVA_HOME" ; echo
RUN echo " --- Graal version:"; native-image --version; echo "$GRAALVM_HOME" ; echo

# Try to install maven
RUN yum update \
    && yum install -y \
    wget unzip tar gzip
...
RUN echo " --- Maven version:"; mvn --version; echo "$M2_HOME" ; echo

yum does not exist.
I tried also dnf, apt-get, ...
Which package manager is used for this image?

TLDR; It's microdnf
Using ls -la /usr/bin can help finding this out.
